# How do I display this pypi download in the md file?

Tags: markdown

I've seen this in many places, but I don't know how to do it.

[image]

Comment: It's an image. Markdown can't make that without an image.

Comment: Would you like a badge? Maybe this (https://pepy.tech/) is useful for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That project appears to be using [Shields.io](https://shields.io/), which you can also use for free. It works by grabbing datas from APIs and creating images from that API, which you can then render as Markdown code.

### Build badge

Use the [build page](https://shields.io/category/build) and figure out which build system your project is using (if any). If you don't already have a build system, [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) is free for open source projects. Once you've decided on a build system, click it on the build page, enter the required URL fields, and use `Copy Markdown` from the dropdown button to get your Markdown code

### Package version and download badges

If you have a package published on PyPi, you can use the following Markdown badge code, replacing `PACKAGE` with your package's name.

```
![PyPI](https://img.shields.io/pypi/v/PACKAGE?label=pypi%20package)
![PyPI - Downloads](https://img.shields.io/pypi/dm/PACKAGE)
```